# Who is allowed to invite people to a Minecraft Realm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I'm considering buying a subscription to Minecraft Realms (on PC) as a gift for somebody I know. Mojang doesn't have a gift option, and I don't want to spoil the surprise, so I was thinking I'd just buy it myself and give them access.

If I do this, will the recipient be able to turn around and invite their own friends? Can I grant them "admin" access to the server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, only the person who paid for the Realm can add people (source: am op on realms)
I would recommend printing out a picture like this:

[image: Minecraft Realms logo]
<sub>(source: [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/images/realms/about-logo.png))</sub>

Write on the piece of paper, explaining that you are paying for a Realms subscription.
Fold the paper up, and wrap it in a box.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do instead is go to EB games, or GameStop and buy a minecraft realms subscription card and give that to him.