# How do I make another person be able to invite people into my Minecraft Realm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I have a Minecraft Realm, but I cannot give others access to the configuration page, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot give others access to the configuration page, only the person who purchased the realm can access it. This is explained better at [Who is allowed to invite people to a Minecraft Realm?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/195039/who-is-allowed-to-invite-people-to-a-minecraft-realm)

Comment: Huge bummer. :( Oh well, thanks for the answer!